# Displaying image in jquery after post() request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I want to display an image file on my html page which I am receiving after sending a JQuery post() request to the server as shown in the code below.

I have commented where I am having the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $.post("http://10.10.129.164:8080/picsOnDemand/sendcphoto/cphoto", {

        clientid: "1234567890",

      },
      function(data) {

        $('#blah').attr('src', data); //What should I code here? 

      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="newimage" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <p>I Am Now A Mobile Developer!!</p>
      <img id="blah" src="" height="200" width="200" alt="Image preview...">
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
      <h1>Footer Text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

From the server side I am sending an image file in response as shown in the code below:

```
@Path("/sendcphoto")
public class SendCPhotoRequested {
@POST
@Path("/cphoto")
@Produces("image/jpeg") 
public Response getCPhoto(@FormParam("clientid") String clientid){

     File file = new File("C:\\Users\\nmn\\workspace1\\clientimages\\"+clientid+".jpg");
     System.out.println("File sent");
     ResponseBuilder builder = javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok((Object) file);
     builder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=clientpic.jpg");
    return builder.build();
}
}
```

Kindly please help, I have been searching for this but I have not got a single answer which worked for me.

Comment: You can generate a URL for the image from the server and send it in the response. Then the above code for showing image should work as expected.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

look here, hope this helps

Comment: put debugger just before $('#blah').attr('src', data); and check data object in console

Comment: mean what  kind of result you are getting

Comment: @Dhaval It's all image data. I have used Advanced Rest Client extension to test the webservice and it is showing image that server is sending.

Answer (score 1):

As Adarsh Konchady said, you could return the URL for the image so you can display it with your current code.

You could also return the image content as a base64 string and [display it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html) using [data URI](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) :

```
$('#blah').attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64, ' + data);
```

Comment: man, when you are just duplicating comments, please, at least, mark them as usefull

Comment: I did not duplicate it on purpose, I just saw that the comment had one of the answer I provided sooner than me, so I quote the author.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the image into base64 string and send it to your view .

```
Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
```

and simply set the base64 string in the image src like below.

```
 $('#blah').attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64, ' + data);
```